# How to separate single string into columns in table in R

Tags: r

In R I have a table with each row containing a single string:

### Input

```
input <- c("05/20/20 14:00 adam", "02/12/19 13:24 eric")
```

(these are single strings)

How do you split the string into multiple columns to this

```
Date       Time   Name
"05/20/20" 14:00 "adam"
"02/12/19" 13:24 "eric"
```

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(input, " ")))`

Comment: @AllanCameron it does successfully split it by space but the number of expected columns is different. In the example above instead of the three cols expected, there were five with some columns containing blank space or a number (the single string is separated by only a single space though)

Comment: also `read.table(text = input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr::separate()` works for that:

Create your data example:

```
input <- data.frame(
  a = c("05/20/20 14:00 adam",
        "02/12/19 13:24 eric"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Separate intro three columns:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(input,
         a,
         into = c("date", "time", "name"),
         sep = " ")
```

This works for the example you gave. In case your data contains irregularities, the additional arguments (i.e. extra & fill) of `separate()` allow you to define how to handle these.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and I found one of my issues earlier was a double space that didn't display properly so I just removed them with regex!

Comment: Feel free to upvote/ mark as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `separate` inside the `tidyverse` package to do so. Just substitute `nameColumn` by the actual column name in your data (without quotes).

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  #Split character column into 3 columns, separating by blank space
  separate(col = nameColumn,
           into = c("Date","Time","Name"),
           sep = " ")
```